# Access Cocoa framework storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have swift Cocoa Touch framework with two controller classes and storyboard. when i tried to `instantiateViewController` from one class to another, it's not working, it shows storyboard not visible.

I am able to initiate the *test.storyboard* from the baseproject using:

```
 if let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testProject", ofType: "framework", inDirectory: "Frameworks") {
            let bundle = (Bundle(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlString) as URL))
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "test", bundle: bundle)
            let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestViewcontroller")
            self.show(vc, sender: nil)
 }
```

[image]

I want to instantiate the second view controller on button click of the first one. Right now I'm using this code block for initiate, but it's not working.

```
 if let urlString =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testProject", ofType: "framework", inDirectory: "Frameworks") {
            let bundle = (Bundle(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlString) as URL))
            let secondvc = UIStoryboard(name: "test", bundle: bundle).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewc") as! secondcontroller

            self.show(secondvc, sender: nil)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i have found the solution for the issue.

```
@IBAction func back(_ sender: AnyObject) {
     let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: Maincontroller.self)
     let secondvc = UIStoryboard(name: "test", bundle: frameworkBundle).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewc") as! secondcontroller
     self.present(secondvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Inside testProject -> Maincontroller.swift, have to add the above code block.